# Wanting DIV to disappear when clicked and replaced by another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a DIV to replaced by another DIV when clicked. Right now I have it so that the first DIV appears and then disappears when other DIVs are clicked but when I try to get the other DIVS to appear when clicked, the first DIV pops up with it. Here is a link to the page http://melinajesser.com/ArchFitters/womens.php, you can click on the Walk image and it is fine but click on the seasonal image and it messes up. How can I fix this?

```
<div id="infor1">
  <div class="side col-md-4 align-center">
    <p>Full EVA Midsole Provides Signature Hoka Cushioning</p>
    <img src="images/valorwomensside.png">
  </div>

  <div class="bottom col-md-4 align-center">
    <p>Early-Stage Meta-Rocker Provides Propulsion</p>
    <img src="images/valorwomensbottom.png">
  </div>

  <div class="description col-md-4 align-center">
    <p>Comfort reigns supreme in the VALOR from the Comfort-Frame lycra upper to the Ultrasize midsole that provides the signature HOKA ONE ONE cushioned ride. Built on an Early-Stage-Meta-Rocker for propulsion, the Valor is a smooth-riding shoe that is best suited for running on man-made surfaces.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="infor2">
  <div class="side col-md-4 align-center">
    <p>Lightweight, padded contour cork footbed</p>
    <img src="images/trulieside.png">        
  </div>

<div class="bottom col-md-4 align-center">
    <p>Lightweight Rubber</p>
    <img src="images/truliebottom.png">
</div>

<div class="description col-md-4 align-center">
    <p>A truly scrumptious leather sandal made in Spain. Man made woven hook and loop straps provide a custom feeling fit. Incredible comfort comes from the lightweight, padded, contour cork-polyurethane footbed lined in suede.</p>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(
 function(){
    $("#walk").click(function () {
        $("#infor1").toggle("slow");
    });

 });

$(document).ready(
 function(){
    $("#run").click(function () {
        $("#infor1").fadeToggle();
    }); 
 });

$(document).ready(
 function(){
    $("#seas").click(function () {
        $("#infor1").fadeToggle();
    });
 });

$(document).ready(
 function(){
    $("#seas").click(function () {
        $("#infor2").toggle("slow");
    });

 });

$(document).ready(
 function(){
    $("#run").click(function () {
        $("#infor2").fadeToggle();
    }); 
 });

$(document).ready(
 function(){
    $("#walk").click(function () {
        $("#infor2").fadeToggle();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to wrap each click function in a document ready they can go in the same one, that being said you should use a class to attach the click function or bind it to a handler.

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e){
   //do stuff here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6w0v8nw3/

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($(id).is(':visible')) {
            $(id).slideUp('fast');
            return false;
        }
        $('.info:visible').slideUp('fast');
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideDown('slow');
    });
});`

Have a link, make the anchor tag the id of the container you want to toggle.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you!! This was exactly what I was needing!